# How to produce empty paramter in an Option?

Tags: polkadot-js, api, query

In the screenshot below the OptionSelect is disabled, which produces info of an array of accounts rather than just one single.

How do you replicate this  option when curating a call?

Using `api.query.system.account` as an example.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, this is using the `entries` api, returning all values in the map, rather than a specific value in the map.

This is documented here: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.other#map-keys--entries

So you can write some code like:

```js
if (global.pageSize == 0) {
    // This will be a long query...
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Querying all users... this may take a while.";
    all_accounts = await substrate.query.system.account.entries();
} else {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = `Querying ${global.pageSize} users... please wait.`;
    all_accounts = await substrate.query.system.account.entriesPaged({ args: [], pageSize: global.pageSize, startKey: global.lastKey });
}
```

Taken from: https://github.com/shawntabrizi/substrate-balance-snapshot/blob/master/snapshot.js